# Managing theme from firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, themes

Is there a way to change themes dynamically from an add-on based on some criteria?
Or at least change the header picture.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: For which version of Firefox? The API changed in Firefox 4.

Comment: i'm currently working on 3.6.17.. but if i want to make my extension work on version 4 I'll have to rewrite it based on your saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know preferences. Anyway I managed to solve the issue using:

```
$toolbar=document.getElementById('navigator-toolbox'); $statusbar=document.getElementById('status-bar');     
$toolbar.style.setProperty('background-image',%img%, 'important'); $statusbar.style.setProperty('background-image', %img%, 'important');
```

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox before version 4:

If the `extensions.dss.enabled` preference is set, set the `general.skins.selectedSkin` preference to the theme's internal name. Otherwise set the `extensions.lastSelectedSkin` preference to the theme's internal name and restart Firefox. Note: This is for standard themes, I don't know whether this applies to Personas.

For Firefox 4 and later:

Obtain a reference to the theme object from the [Add-on Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager) and set its `userDisabled` property to false. If it is a Persona, then it will apply instantly, and its `isActive` property will become true. Otherwise you will need to restart Firefox.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, but what i meant in (from an add-on) is that I'm building an add-on and want to change the theme/skin dynamically. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @Suad If you're building an add-on you should know what preferences are. Or which part did of my answer did you not understand?